# Generate quarters within start date and end date and calculate how many days fall within each quarter

Tags: r, date, formatting, date-range, as.date

I am quite new to R and have a question, hopefully someone will know the answer.

I have a (small sample) dataset which looks like this:

```
structure(list(ID = 1:6, Date_Start = structure(c(7305, 7702, 
12114, 9714, 11819, 8418), class = "Date"), Date_stop = structure(c(10957, 
11355, 15767, 10111, 17422, 12949), class = "Date"), Start_Range_1 = structure(c(7731, 
8068, 13304, 9863, NA, NA), class = "Date"), Stop_Range_1 = structure(c(8129, 
8070, 13308, 9867, NA, NA), class = "Date"), Days_Range_1 = structure(c(3L, 
2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("#VALUE!", "2", "398", "4"), class = "factor"), 
    Start_Range_2 = structure(c(8170, 8566, 13878, NA, 11853, 
    NA), class = "Date"), Stop_Range_2 = structure(c(8202, 8593, 
    13893, NA, 12072, NA), class = "Date"), Days_Range_2 = structure(c(5L, 
    4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("#VALUE!", "15", "219", "27", 
    "32"), class = "factor"), Start_Range_3 = structure(c(9544, 
    9869, 14029, NA, NA, NA), class = "Date"), Stop_Range_3 = structure(c(9573, 
    9870, 14042, NA, NA, NA), class = "Date"), Days_Range_3 = structure(c(4L, 
    2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("#VALUE!", "1", "13", "29"
    ), class = "factor"), Start_Range_4 = structure(c(9993, 10267, 
    14621, NA, NA, NA), class = "Date"), Stop_Range_4 = structure(c(9996, 
    10272, 14625, NA, NA, NA), class = "Date"), Days_Range_4 = structure(c(2L, 
    4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("#VALUE!", "3", "4", "5"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("ID", 
"Date_Start", "Date_stop", "Start_Range_1", "Stop_Range_1", "Days_Range_1", 
"Start_Range_2", "Stop_Range_2", "Days_Range_2", "Start_Range_3", 
"Stop_Range_3", "Days_Range_3", "Start_Range_4", "Stop_Range_4", 
"Days_Range_4"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

[image: data screenshot]

```
'data.frame':   6 obs. of  15 variables:
 $ ID           : int  1 2 3 4 5 6
 $ Date_Start   : Date, format: "1990-01-01" "1991-02-02" ...
 $ Date_stop    : Date, format: "2000-01-01" "2001-02-02" ...
 $ Start_Range_1: Date, format: "1991-03-03" "1992-02-03" ...
 $ Stop_Range_1 : Date, format: "1992-04-04" "1992-02-05" ...
 $ Days_Range_1 : Factor w/ 4 levels "#VALUE!","2",..: 3 2 4 4 1 1
 $ Start_Range_2: Date, format: "1992-05-15" "1993-06-15" ...
 $ Stop_Range_2 : Date, format: "1992-06-16" "1993-07-12" ...
 $ Days_Range_2 : Factor w/ 5 levels "#VALUE!","15",..: 5 4 2 1 3 1
 $ Start_Range_3: Date, format: "1996-02-18" "1997-01-08" ...
 $ Stop_Range_3 : Date, format: "1996-03-18" "1997-01-09" ...
 $ Days_Range_3 : Factor w/ 4 levels "#VALUE!","1",..: 4 2 3 1 1 1
 $ Start_Range_4: Date, format: "1997-05-12" "1998-02-10" ...
 $ Stop_Range_4 : Date, format: "1997-05-15" "1998-02-15" ...
 $ Days_Range_4 : Factor w/ 4 levels "#VALUE!","3",..: 2 4 3 1 1 1
```

I want to generate columns with all quarters between Start_date and End_date for each unique ID_number (quarter 1 uptill around 95-100, however different for each ID number).

Besides that I want to know how many days of each date range (start_range_1, stop_range_1, days_range_1) fall within these quarters (starting from Start_date for each unique ID). Sometimes a range might spread over 2 quarters and in case it does, I would like to know how many days fall within the first quarter of the range and how many days in the second quarter of the range. So I need the total number of days in each quarter of all the date ranges (30 in total).

Output would ideally be something like this:

[image: desired output]

Hopefully someone can help me! many thanks in advance

Comment: please dput data you want, images are not really that helpful.  You should definitly look at lubridate

Comment: Hi, it would be helpful if you could try and create a *small* example dataset, that is representative of your real data, and also give the expected outcome please. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example gives advice in producing examples.

Comment: Thanks for the comments already, I tried to update the questions and added your recommendations, hopefully this is what you meant

Comment: Anyone any idea?